# how to use react-native app as a library like .aar file in native android or IOS

Tags: react-native

i have created a chatbot in react-native. i don't want to make it as a diff chatbot app. i want to make it as  global library like AAR file. so that any customer can able to use it in native android or IOS.  is there any way to make it as a library so that anyone can trigger my chatbot by clicking on button from their native app. and any how they pass some data to chatbot.

Comment: Hey did you find any solution? i have the same issue, i want to build my RN app as .aar and use it in other apps.